# Create method template C# in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, templates, methods

I can't seem to find anything about this online, it may not be possible, but I wanted to double check here:

I want to make a standardisation for methods the way I use them.

For example, if I create a lot of methods with the same variable, is it possible to make some sort of template where I create a variable on top of the class and automatically use it in a method?

An example:

On top of the class:

```
Public int index;
```

The method:

```
Public void DoSomething(int input)
{
    index = input;
}
```

If I do something like this a lot, is it possible to template it?

For something as small as above, the usage may not look that special, but I'm asking for something larger, but wanted to keep the question clean

Comment: You mean something like [code snippets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/code-snippets?view=vs-2019)?

Comment: Yeah something like that exactly, but where i can also choose the name of the variables. For example mtd(DoSomething, Index) and then twice tabbing to create the code from my question. But I'm not sure if it works with variables etc.

Comment: Even if it's not possible, your reaction is already a great help, and a perfect answer for me :) I totally forgot about this functionality, thanks.

Comment: I have found it! Can do it by using code snippets and adding the variables in the snippet xml as an editable litteral in the declarations: <Declarations> <Literal Editable="true"><ID>variable</ID><Default>index</Default></Literal></Declarations>